# Notation for showing many variables are greater than other variables

Tags: notation

Suppose I have a set of variables, $x$, $y$, $z$ that are all greater than other variables $a$, $b$ yet we know no relationship between the first set or second set of variables. So we want to show $x > a$, $x > b$, $y> a$, $y> b$, $z > a$, $z > b$ concisely. What is the best way to show this? Is the following accurate? $x, y, z > a, b$?

Comment: How about $x,y,z > \max(a,b)$.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437961/comparison-notation-for-sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would either write out

$$x, y, z \text{ are all greater than both }a\text{ and }b$$

or, if I wanted to express it symbolically,

$$\operatorname{min}(x,y,z)\gt \operatorname{max}(a,b).$$